# Volca Sample with Beatstep Pro as Master Clock and Keystep Pro as Slave

Tags: midi

I just added a Keystep Pro to my setup and am having difficulties integrating it with my existing gear.

My setup looks like this (with a few noted differences) and everything is connected via MDI.

[image]

- BSP Out to KSP In
- KSP Out to Mindtech MIDI Thru Fiter In
- Mindtech MIDI Thru Fiter Out to 3 Korg Volcas In

BSP acts as the master and the KSP as slave. I'm able to control channels 15 and 16 from both controllers as expected – MIDI messages on channels 15 and 16 pass through the KSP. However MIDI messages from the drum sequencer on the BSP don't make it to the Sample (it works when I connect it directly as I have the new firmware). I know the KSP doesn't support the Sample yet, but the messages on channels 1-10 should pass through when I play drum pads on the BSP.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it says "keystep pro" in the description and the picture shows a plain keystep? (and in case of midi thru, that makes a huge difference). I assume the picture is correct, not the description?

Comment: This is an image taken from a YouTube video with a similar setup. They are using the KP while my setup has a KSP. I've since learned that the KSP doesn't support MIDI Thru and separated myself from the unit.